# Is executable permission mode S used for anything?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, execute-command

If you add the setuid bit for a file's permission where you have execute permission, it changes the `x` to an `s` to mean that if you execute that file, it will execute as the owner of the file rather than the person actually executing it.

But I also noticed that if you add `s` permission but remove `x` permission it changes to an `S` in the permissions listing. Somehow this would imply that it could not be executed but it would simultaneously be executed as the owner if it could be executed? Is that right?

Am I misunderstanding this permission? What is it used for? What does it mean?

Comment: It means that it will be run as the owner of the binary. `sudo` and su is an example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### All four combinations exist and are meaningful.

*"Can this file's actual owner run it?"* and *"Who will the system pretend is running this file?"* are two separate questions. All four combinations are possible and meaningful.

Permissions strings displayed by `ls -l` or `stat -c %A` show, in the owner execute position (i.e., in place of `?` in `---?------`), four different characters, one for each combination:

1. `-` means the owner *can't* run the file and, if a non-owner runs it, it runs *as that other user*.
2. `x` means the owner *can* run the file and, if a non-owner runs it, it runs *as that other user*.
3. `S` means the owner *can't* run the file and, if a non-owner runs it, it runs *as the owner instead*.
4. `s` means the owner *can* run the file and, if a non-owner runs it, it runs *as the owner instead*.

The setuid bit and the execute bits are separate bits, and the mode *string* is really just a convenient way of viewing the permission bits, including those. Another way to think about it is:

- `x` or `s` means the execute bit is set. `-` or `S` means it isn't.
- `s` or `S` means the setuid bit is set. `-` or `x` means it isn't.

Similarly, a group may or may not have execute permissions on a file and, if executed, it may or may not be run with a different group identity than that of the user who runs it. To cause a file to run with the group identity of its group owner rather than that of the user who runs it, you would set [the setgid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_executables) (`------s---` or `------S---`).

`S` does not represent a separate mode bit. It is simply a way of signifying that the setuid (or setgid) bit is set but the corresponding  executable bit is not set.

```
$ touch foo
$ chmod u+S foo
chmod: invalid mode: ‘u+S’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

### You can examine the bits themselves.

To see that these are separate bits, use the `%a` format specifier for `stat` instead of `%A`. To simplify things, I've unset all the other mode bits.

```
$ touch a b c d
$ chmod u=,g=,o= a
$ chmod u=x,g=,o= b
$ chmod u=s,g=,o= c
$ chmod u=xs,g=,o= d
$ stat -c '%A %n' a b c d
---------- a
---x------ b
---S------ c
---s------ d
$ stat -c '%04a %n' a b c d
0000 a
0100 b
4000 c
4100 d
```

That makes it clear... if you're comfortable with [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). If you want to see it in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (they *are* [bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) after all) you can convert the representations:

```
$ stat -c '%a %n' a b c d | perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf("%012b", oct($&))/e'
000000000000 a
000001000000 b
100000000000 c
100001000000 d
```

### Setuid sets the effective user ID, not the real user ID.

Execute bits control whether or not an attempt [to run a file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html) may succeed, while setuid/setgid bits control whose identity the new process runs under if it is allowed to be created. So there is nothing inconsistent or surprising about the combination of permissions `S` represents (`-x,+s`). This would be so even if an executable running as its owner because its owner really ran it worked exactly the same as an executable running as its owner because someone ran it but it was setuid. But that's not how it works.

The kernel uses more than one number to keep track of the user identity of a running process. One such number is the UID, and another is the EUID. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Process_attributes) for details. The setuid bit causes the EUID (effective user ID) to be changed, but the UID (real user ID) remains the same. One use of this it to allow signals to be exchanged between processes that share a UID but have different EUIDs, but another is that it allows a program that is designed to have its setuid bit set to *check who ran it*.

For example, [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/passwd.1.html) must be setuid, because only root can change entries in the password database:

```
$ ls -l "$(command -v passwd)"
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 54256 May 16 19:37 /usr/bin/passwd
```

`-rwsr-xr-x` has `r-x` at the end, for *others*. Due to the `x`, even users who aren't root or in the root group may run `passwd`. And it has `rws` near the beginning, for *owner*. Due to the `s`, the program runs as root, even when non-owners run it. *But when you run `passwd` yourself, it resets your password, not root's.*

`passwd` is *capable* of performing any change whatsoever to the database of users and passwords, because it runs with root's effective user ID. But it is designed to refuse to change the password of anyone but the user ran it--except when that user is root--because it checks its real user ID.

This is the typical use case of setuid executable: to create an interface that allows one user to cause actions to be performed as another, in a limited way that is checked by the code of the setuid executable. So it is only secure to set the setuid bit (or the setgid bit) on a program that is *designed* to have those permissions.

This is the other piece of the puzzle to understand why the permissions `S` signifies are no enigma: **the power the setuid bit confers *doesn't* achieve the same thing as actually running the program as its owner**, even once the program has been allowed to run.

### Checking UID and EUID with a copy of `id` shows how setuid works.

Okay, well, I'm going to set the setuid bit on an executable that isn't designed for it, to show how the real and effective user IDs are affected.

- The executable will be *a copy* of the [`id`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/id.1.html) program that, among other things, reports its real and effective user IDs. Although this program is not designed to be setuid, it is also not designed to change anything at all--except by producing output--so this is reasonably safe. But you should still delete it afterwards. (Your copy. Not the original.)
- We are using a copy, *not* changing permissions on the original. You do *not* need to use `sudo` or perform any action as root for this.
- To run it as another user, you need a second user account, but you can use `su` to perform actions as *that* user. (By default, the `root` account doesn't allow you to log in as it with a password, so if you make a mistake and run `su` without giving the username you want to switch to, you won't end up accidentally becoming root instead, unless you have also enabled root logins. If you really want to use `sudo -u user` instead of `su user -c`, though, then you can.)

My main user account is called `ek` and my second account is `ek2`. It's fine if yours are different. First, as `ek`, I copy `id` to the current directory (which is somewhere inside my home directory):

```
$ type -a id
id is /usr/bin/id
$ cp /usr/bin/id .
```

The copy has the ownership of the non-root user who copied it, but the original permissions:

```
$ ls -l id /usr/bin/id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ek   ek   39760 Oct  5 11:23 id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39760 Mar  2  2017 /usr/bin/id
```

Passing `-n` to `id` shows names instead of ID numbers, `-u` shows the user (and not other information like groups), and `-r` causes the real user ID to be shown. Without `-r`, `-u` shows the effective user ID. This behavior applies fully to the *copy* of `id` I have just made.

When I run it as a substitute user, the real and effective user IDs are both changed. This is part of how `su` and `sudo` are written, and is no mere result of `su` itself being setuid root, though it is. (This is why I used `passwd` as an example of a typical setuid executable, rather than `su` or `sudo`.) This is our baseline, to see that `id` in the current directory works as expected:

```
$ ./id -nu                # ek runs id, displaying the effective user
ek
$ ./id -nur               # ek runs id, displaying the real user
ek
$ su ek2 -c './id -nu'    # ek2 runs id, displaying the effective user
Password:
ek2
$ su ek2 -c './id -nur'   # ek2 runs id, displaying the real user
Password:
ek2
```

Now I make this local copy of `id` setuid:

```
$ chmod u+s id
$ ls -l id
-rwsr-xr-x 1 ek ek 39760 Oct  5 11:42 id
```

Now when I run it, its real user ID is still that of the user who ran it, while its effective user ID is that of `ek` even when `ek2` runs it:

```
$ ./id -nu                # ek runs id, displaying the effective user
ek
$ ./id -nur               # ek runs id, displaying the real user
ek
$ su ek2 -c './id -nu'    # ek2 runs id, displaying the effective user
Password:
ek
$ su ek2 -c './id -nur'   # ek2 runs id, displaying the real user
Password:
ek2
```

Now I take away executable permissions from the owner but leave them for everyone else:

```
$ chmod u-x id
$ ls -l id
-rwSr-xr-x 1 ek ek 39760 Oct  5 11:42 id
```

`ek2` can still run it as with `ek`'s effective user ID, even though `ek` can't run it:

```
$ ./id -nu                # ek runs id, displaying the effective user
-bash: ./id: Permission denied
$ ./id -nur               # ek runs id, displaying the real user
-bash: ./id: Permission denied
$ su ek2 -c './id -nu'    # ek2 runs id, displaying the effective user
Password:
ek
$ su ek2 -c './id -nur'   # ek2 runs id, displaying the real user
Password:
ek2
```

But, as shown, this did not produce the same result as `ek` actually running it. `ek2` can't really do what `ek` could do if `ek` were allowed to run the program, unless the program allows it.

(Afterwards, I ran `rm id` to remove the file, so I wouldn't have an unnecessary setuid executable lying around in my home directory. Or you could just unset the setuid bit with `chmod -s id`.)

Comment: This is really interesting... thank you for this. Are the existence of effective/real UIDs specifically for this setuid concept?

Answer (score 4):

The output displays `S` if setuid is set, but user permissions do not include execute. However, as long as group or other can execute, the setuid bit has meaning: if somebody other than the owner executes the file, it will run as the owner, which is the intended purpose of setuid. If the owner could execute the file, it would run as their user anyway, so setuid is irrelevant to the owner.

Here's a simple illustration:

```
$ cp $(which whoami) foo
$ sudo chmod u=rs,go+x foo
$ stat -c %A foo
-r-Sr-xr-x
$ ./foo
zsh: permission denied: ./foo
$ sudo -u www-data whoami
www-data
$ sudo -u www-data ./foo
muru
```

Comment: Yes, if nobody had execute permissions, then setuid doesn't have any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed right. Normally it should be `s` when the `x` is set on the file in question. But where the `x` execution bit has been removed then the `s` changes to `S` to inform you that although the setuid is used on that file it is has no `x` set.

In this case that will not even execute since the `x` is not set. Now we have this `-r-Srwxr-x`, which means the `o` -- others still can execute this script. So when you change to any other user than `owner` the script will run

`Info ls`:

```
 ‘s’
      If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit and the corresponding
      executable bit are both set.

 ‘S’
      If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
      corresponding executable bit is not set.
```

Comment: `s` without `x` isn't useless; other users [can still run it as the owner](https://askubuntu.com/a/961816) (and that combination [is consistent and well-defined](https://askubuntu.com/a/962268)). I haven't heard that the reason `ls` and `stat -c %A` show `S` is to caution the user, but I suppose that could be true. I've always figured it was just to show a character other than `s` that would be understood to signify the other possible combination than `-`, `x`, and `s`. I think it may help to revise this and include some material from [that (deleted) answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962074).

Comment: And what part of that other answer would be relevant here and what would be the purpose of removing the `x` for owner of file that others are expected to run with `owner` privileges ?

Comment: Well, currently this answer is useful but, I think, also misleading. It implies a setuid bit has no effect unless the *corresponding* executable bit is set. But unsetting that bit doesn't defeat the purpose of the setuid bit, because the setuid bit as about what happens when *others* run the file, not what happens when the owner runs the file. If the group and other executable bits are *also* removed, though, then that does prevent the setuid bit from having an effect. In [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962074) you explained this, with an example. That's what I think would help out here.

Comment: ok, please take a look at it now is it better?